# Can I call tell that my program is compiler

Tags: c#, compilation

I have written a program which translate string input into complex C# object of some class. This object allows then to perform some operations (Generate something).

Generally here is phases my 'compiler' use:

```
Preprocessing
     |
     v
   Lexer analysis
     |
     v
   Parsing into syntax tree
     |
     v
  Visiting produced tree and generating output object.
     |
     v
   Output
```

this output is my complex C# object. It contains values which were expanded when expression tree were analyzed by visitors.

So my question is, Am I allowed to tell that my program compile this input (so now it's object of class - not a different 'language')

Wiki said:

> A compiler is a computer program (or a set of programs) that transforms source code written in a programming language (the source language) into another computer language (the target language)

and I really don't know becouse teoretically I made transaltion from expression to C# object which can be executed by .NET environment (this plain expression can't be run by environment)

To be more detailed, user provide this input when program runs so it's not any kind of overlay for existing C# compilers.

Comment: The output is a compiled C# class "which can be executed by .NET", so why not.

Comment: I think your program should be called an interpreter or parser because the source is not a programing language or if you call the "input string" a programming language then it could be called a compiler.

Comment: @robot9706 teoretically I call object that is generated by this 'compiler' :)

Comment: No. If your program doesn't result directly in an executable it isn't a compiler. It could be called 'translator' or 'code generator'.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but people will argue with you.

There is a small holdout of people who believe it isn't a compiler unless it outputs native code, which rules out Java and C#.

I think *most* people would go for the `compiler` label if it outputs some kind of bytecode that is run on a physical or virtual machine.

If it compiles from one high-level language to another, the word `transpiler` is usually used.

If your case, I'd say that you have written the first step of a compiler -- or, depending on what your output looks like, you may have written the parser to an `Abstract Syntax Tree`.

Comment: my output is C# instance of some class that is instantied in very specific way based on visitors analysis. So technically, I don't generate new code but use existing otherly adjusted. Maybe it's better to call it interpreting but compilation fits for me more becouse of my feeling that interpreting has only phases "insert code" and then "run code". In my case it's something like "insert code" -> "get based on this code adjusted object" -> "run some method of this object".